# Return the type of a java class implementing an interface

Tags: java, class, generics, types, return

I have a flag telling me which class type to use. A static method should be used to retrieve the right class. The class type is needed as an input for a generic method.

```
public class Config{
    public static int flag = 1;
}

public interface A {
    public abstract int getResult();
}

public class A1 implements A{
    public int getResult{
    // ...
    }
}

public class A2 implements A{
    public int getResult{
    // ...
    }
}

public class AType{

    public static Class getType(){
        switch (Config.flag) {
    case 1:
        return A1.class;
    case 2:
        return A2.class;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

The return type of "getType()" is wrong. I already tried some generic return types, but as it seems it does not work like that to retrieve a class type for further usage...

Any ideas how to return a different class type depending on a configuration flag?

I need the class type (A1 or A2) as an input for generic methods like this one:

```
public static <T extends Message> T[] getArrayFromStream(DataInputStream in, Class<T> returnType)
        throws IOException {
    return getArrayFromStream(in, returnType, new Object[0]);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the return type is wrong"? Is it a compile error? What is the error? What generic return types have you tried?

Comment: I tried a similar code and it work perfectly fine to me. What's your error?

Comment: If I use "Class" as a return type, the error message of eclipse is "This method must return a result of type Class".

When I use a return type like "Class<? extends A>", then the error is "This method must return a result of type Class<? extends Psid>".

When using "Class<A>", then eclipse tells me "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<A1> to Class<A>".

Comment: where are you getting these errors? At what line of code? Specifically, when you use `Class<? extends A>`, at what line of code do you get the compile error `must return a type Class<? extends Psid>`?

Comment: I get the error at the first line of the getType() method: "public static Class<? extends A> getType(){" where "getType()" is marked red.

Comment: I don't get that error in Eclipse. What is `Psid`? Where is that coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess (given the lack of information) is that you are trying to do this:

```
Class clazz = getType();
A instance = clazz.newInstance();
```

If that is the case you need this...

```
public Class<? extends A> getType(){...}
```

and then

```
Class<? extends A> clazz = getType();
A instance = clazz.newInstance();
```

Comment: Hi, I already tried this out, but it did not work.

I need the class type (A1 or A2) as an input for a generic method in a bigger project where I can't just change the generic method.

The method looks like that:
public static <T extends Message> T[] getArrayFromStream(DataInputStream in, Class<T> returnType)
   throws IOException {
  return getArrayFromStream(in, returnType, new Object[0]);
 }

Comment: I don't think you have given us enough context to help you. Try posting more of the code because when we try the above code, it compiles.

Comment: -_- ...I just realized that I had a problem with my swith-case clause and eclipse just returned a misleading error. :-(

=> Problem solved. Thank you for your help! The comment "it compiles" was really helpful! ^^